# Apache2 is redirecting to https

Tags: ssl, https

I installed SSL (stupidly) to encrypt the data being sent, the only trouble was my subdomain was redirecting to my main. I changed my default virtual host back to the original settings and also typed a2dismod ssl. Now when ever I type in www.domain.com it redirects to https://www.domain.com and then says SSL Connection Error.

I'm hoping to either get SSL working on the main+sub or just remove completely. Has anyone got any idea why it's redirecting to Https?

My VirtualHosts file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/folder
#SSLEngine on
#SSLCertificationFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
#SSLCertificationKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sub.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sub
#SSLEngine on
#SSLCertificationFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
#SSLCertificationKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Now if I un-comment the lines with # on and change *:80 to *:443 it redirects to the main site with SSL enabled...

Answer (score 0):

You are enabling mod_ssl (with the "SSLEngine on" directive) on a HTTP Virtual Host on TCP/80. You need to set up different Virtual Hosts bound to the TCP/443 port, on only enable mod_ssl on these.
Otherwise, mod_ssl expect an HTTPS connection on port 80 and, seeing that your browser is speaking HTTP, tries to redirect the browser to https://www.domain.com.